# the tilde key is mapped incorrectly; what setting do ineed to change to fix it?

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, system-settings

I'm a newbie user doing rather well at my first O/S install.  This particular snag I cannot figure out.

The upper left key (just below the ESC) is marked with a tilde as the shift value and the "back single quote" (there's probably a proper name for it), if the key is pressed unshifted.  When I press this key I get a ">" (when shifted), and a "<" when pressed on its own.  It is the only key that appears to have an "alternate" definition.  I'm not certain if this is a keyboard definition, or a region setting or something else.

I don't know how to check these settings (or where).  I am not even sure if the approach to the problem is to replace a setting or change the internal key definition for the one key.  Whatever is the easier/cleaner solution is fine with me.  I'm hoping the problem is a common set-up problem that an experienced installer will recognize and know how best to rectify.

The version of ubuntu is 16.04 LTS and the language I intended is English.  Sometimes I select English(US) and sometimes I select English(CA).  I don't recall what I selected on any occasions I was asked during the installation process.  This was installed as a dual-boot on a MacBook Pro (12,1).

Thank you in advance for your time, and I apologize if this is a question that has been asked repeatedly - I'm sure it has been, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: I suspect it's a MacBook Pro issue. Please check out the answer to the question marked as a "possible duplicate" and let us know if it helps.

Comment: Thank You for reading and reaching out.  I have read the link provided and admit that it seems rather similar (and may lead to the solution ??), but there are differences.  The greater than and less than characters are displayed when I press the > and < buttons, so the problem is not a SWAP.  (and the @ button also works correctly).  But it does allude to the fact that it may be a Ubuntu-on-a-mac problem.  If it was that simple a cause, I would imagine there would be MANY instances of this problem being reported.

Comment: Ok... But why not still try it? By running `setxkbmap -option apple:badmap` in a terminal window you can test what the result would be without saving it persistently.

Comment: Sorry, I just read the symptoms of the other solution.  It WORKED (I'm a little shocked, but even more grateful.  Thank you, Thank you, Thank you.

Comment: I hit "add comment" there by mistake.  Your last comment suggested that this would not be persistent.  How would I be able to do that - and would that cover ALL users (i.e. would that become a GLOBAL change) or would I have to repeat this process for each user?

Comment: Great that it works! The answer in the duplicate question shows how you can make the change persistent and global, i.e. affecting other users and the guest session.

Comment: I have followed the link, read and applied the entire answer (i.e. edited the /etc/defaults/keyboard file and it has resolved my problem as you stated.  I thank you profusely.  Unfortunately the "yes this solved my problem" button has disappeared, so I am at a bit of a loss as to what to do now.  Although to my eye, the problem sounded similiar, the proof was in the pudding - your fix was bang on, I am up and running and I am very grateful.  Thank You once again.  (I'll re-read the tutorial on what to do.)  Case Closed - kudos points to Gunnar Hjalmarsson.

Comment: Glad to hear that. There are only comments here, not an actual answer, but if you want you can upvote the linked answer. ;)